# pd.read_excel only files where filename contains substring within past 5 days

Tags: python, pandas, loops, filenames

I'm trying to read a few excel files from a directory to append them. I've tried a few things but i cannot get it to work. when i first append the whole directory my memory blows up.

Basically i have a directory with .xlsx files let's say: H:\data  in here are +300 files with similar file names like: files.01-01-2020_amsterdam.xlsx i would like to import only the 5 files from the last 5 days. i've come up with:

```
today = pd.datetime.now().date()
today = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
5days = today -5
```

it works if i want just one file:

```
os.chdir('H:\data')
df = pd.read_excel("files." + today  + "_amsterdam" +'.xlsx', sheet_name=0)
```

but how can i get 5 files into one df? so if the date part is anywhere between today and 5days? i suppose with a loop somehow but i'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

ps. you can't start a variable name with an integer

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import date
import os

amountOfDays = 5

for i in range(amountOfDays):
    dateOfDay = date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    dateOfDay = dateOfDay.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

    os.chdir('H:\data')
    path = "files." + str(dateOfDay) + '_amsterdam' + '.xlsx'

    if i == 0:
        df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=0)
    else:
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=0),ignore_index=True)
```